# SSE Access Violation crash on object creation

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, crash, sse

I created an SSE powered vector class.

I create an instance of it inside a periodically called drawback function, which causes to crash at the start of my program. The issue doesn't happen in the case of declaring it global.

> Error message: Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution
>   time : 3.471 s

Here is the simplified class:

```
#include <mmintrin.h>

alignas(16) class v3
{
  public:

    // constructors
    inline v3() : m(_mm_setzero_ps()) {}
    inline v3(float x, float y, float z) : m(_mm_set_ps(0, z, y, x)) {}

    inline v3(__m128 m) : m(m) {}


    // Member variables
    union
    {
        struct { float x, y, z; };
        __m128 m;
    };
};
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is the error message? At what point in the code is it raised?

Comment: Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 3.471 s
It happens relatively at the start of the program.

Comment: You should run your program in debugger and then provide the code where crash happens.  Most likely you run into misalignment issues.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it is related to the moment when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Are you putting it in an STL container? STL containers don't align.

Comment: No, I just create an object.

Comment: I'd be surprised if it affects your error, but I suggest that you put the alignment requirement on the member union instead of the class itself for future-proofing.

Answer (score 1):

Error code `0xC0000005` is an access violation. When SSE is involved that invariably means that you are attempting misaligned memory access. You'll need to work out which operation uses operands that are not aligned.

Comment: There are no operations, I just create an object.

Comment: @plasmacel ...and run its default constructor.

Comment: I do the following line (which causes the error): v3 testvec;

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you are using Visual C++, since you mentioning windows-style error codes. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx), Visual C++ doesn't support `alignas` or `alignof`. You may have better luck using `std::aligned_storage`, e.g.:

```
union {
    _m128 m;
    struct { float x,y,z };
    std::aligned_storage<16> storage;
};
```

Comment: I use GCC so it is supported. For backward compatibility I made a compiler attribute macro.